# Integrating Roundcube mail efficiently - literally - has anybody done it?

Tags: php, roundcube

Hi guys I've integrated roundcube mail albeit pretty bluntly in my application i.e I just have it open in an iframe with the login credentials passed through via session variables. It works but the problem is that its very darn slow - and I'm beginning to assume its because of the iframe thing . I was wondering if anyone has been able to integrate the program in their own websites in a more efficient way - simply doing an include(index.php ) on the program doesn't work obviously...

Comment: Have you tried comparing the iframe speed with just having roundcube open by itself? Because an iframe shouldn't affect performance. It's just like having another tab open on your browser, except its inside of the page.

Comment: Oh no... its jsut slow. Its one of my choices for webmail client at (mt). @mail is only slightly better speed wise but is much more usable in my opinion (especially if you use the "simple ajax" mode).

Comment: Well the thing is that I would like to integrate a webclient - however I'm not so sure if I have the time to build one from scratch or form code libraries. I don't need something very complex just an application where I can see my inbound and outgoing emails. WOuld it be a wise decision to build from scratch using third party libraries like Zend Mail?

Comment: Never wise to reinvent the wheel (unless it's for educational purposes). Plenty of open source clients/APIs to work from.

Comment: Well if you just need to list items then i think that would be pretty easy.

Comment: Well not just list items I need basically just the read emails part of a webmail client - after that I wish to build upon it like relenta.org - they have some kind of email client built up and you can assign tasks to messages and create contacts from them etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you use the following plugin as a base for your efforts?

https://svn.roundcube.net/trunk/roundcubemail/plugins/http_authentication/

Let me know if this helps, I'm happy to provide more help/pointers. I'm one of the RoundCube leads.

Cheers,
Till

Comment: Thanks but basically the only issue I have is with the view mails. It seems to be quite slow and I guess its because for every action it makes an IMAP call. I've been tweaking roundcube mail for a while though and required something more on the line of having it within my page - I dont have any problem with authentication although the solution you'e given is a lot cleaner than what I've go running :)

Comment: Ah, well, if you want to share some war stories email me at till-\at/-roundcube-\dot/-net.

As in "viewing emails", maybe look into the caching. If that doesn't help and IMAP remains the overhead, I'd suggest you look into nginx for imap proxy/loadbalancing and imapproxy.

Comment: @danorton: You couldn't be bothered to just edit and fix the link?

I just did it myself, wasn't aware that I have to monitor answers from over two years ago to make sure the links I provided at that time are still up to date today.

Comment: #1 - I have no control over when my edits are reviewed, #2 - I didn’t know the correct link. You seem to take it personally. It’s only a score, and only a numeric one, at that. It got your attention quickly and it was corrected and I have removed my downvote. The system works.